# Solve $(x^{2}+1)e^{-x}=u$ for $x$?

Tags: lambert-w, transcendental-equations

I need to solve the following equation for $x$

$(x^{2}+1)e^{-x}=u$

I tried Lambert's W function but couldn't find solution for $x$.

Comment: I made some significant improvements. Check my edit.

Comment: There is a solution using Mathematica’s [inverse gamma regularized](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseGammaRegularized.html)

Answer (score 4):

Just for your curiosity, there is a solution in terms of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) writing
$$e^{-x}=\frac u{(x+i)(x-i)}$$ (look at equation $(4)$ in the linked paper).

This being said, it is not very useful from a practical point of view and you will need some numerical method.

The case where $u$ is large is interesting to work. "Ignoring" the $1$, we have an approximate solution
$$x_0=-2 W\left(\frac{\sqrt{u}}{2}\right)$$

Let us see how it works for $u=10^k$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & x_0 & x \\
 1 & -1.49643 &  -1.30664 \\
 2 & -2.65345 &  -2.57381 \\
 3 & -4.09045 &  -4.05078 \\
 4 & -5.72178 &  -5.69932 \\
 5 & -7.48668 &  -7.47267 \\
 6 & -9.34568 &  -9.33629 \\
 7 & -11.2732 &  -11.2666 \\
 8 & -13.2523 &  -13.2474 \\
 9 & -15.2713 &  -15.2675 \\
 10 & -17.3219 &  -17.3189
\end{array}
\right)$$

Looking at the iterations for $u=1234$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n\\
 0 & -4.232452826 \\
 1 & -4.195927899 \\
 2 & -4.194973626 \\
 3 & -4.194972995
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

The above approximation can be significantly improve writing
$$x=-2 W\left(\frac{\sqrt{u}}{2}\big[1+\epsilon(u)\big] \right)$$ and using one iteration of Halley method starting with $\epsilon(u)=0$. This gives
$$\epsilon(u)=-\frac{2 \left(t+1\right)^2 \left(2t+1\right)}{t^2\left(32 t^3+80t^2+70 t+23\right)} \qquad \text{where} \qquad t=W\left(\frac{\sqrt{u}}{2}\right)$$

Repeating the calculation for $u=1234$, this gives as initial estimate $-4.19498$.

Repeating the calculation with $u=10^k$ would lead to
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & x_0 & x \\
 1 & -1.3084265 &  -1.3066351 \\
 2 & -2.5738946 &  -2.5738063 \\
 3 & -4.0507872 &  -4.0507789 \\
 4 & -5.6993250 &  -5.6993237 \\
 5 & -7.4726712 &  -7.4726709 \\
 6 & -9.3362865 &  -9.3362865 \\
 7 & -11.266569 &  -11.266569 \\
 8 & -13.247397 &  -13.247397 \\
 9 & -15.267528 &  -15.267528 \\
 10 & -17.318923 &  -17.318923
\end{array}
\right)$$ which seems to be significantly better. We can still improve using for example one iteration of Householder method
$$\epsilon(u)=-\frac{3 \left(t+1\right)^2 \left(64t^4+192 t^3+220 t^2+116t+23\right)}
{1536t^8+7680 t^7+16320 t^6+19008t^5+12864 t^4+4800t^3+732 t^2-62t-23}$$
For $k=1$, this would give $-1.3068117$.

We could also do a Taylor expansion in terms of $\epsilon(u)$, then use series reversion and get
$$\epsilon(u)=-\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{10} a_n t^n}{384 t (2 t+1)^{11}}$$ where tha $a_n$'s are
$$\{1672,10847,55626,216212,616440,1275264,1888512,1950720,1333248,540672,98304\}$$
For $k=1$, this would give $-1.3067888$.